# Maya Python: Lock transforms of a keyframe

Tags: python, maya, mel

So I've been looking for awhile but haven't found anything.
What I'm trying to do is lock the ability to move keyframes forward or backwards so if there is a key on the 10th frame, I don't want to accidentally shift it to 8th or 20th frame, I only want to be able to shift up and down in the graph editor on the various translate curves

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there's no Python/MEL command to lock keframe's axis, because there's no need to do it programmatically. So, just press a <kbd>shift</kbd> and slide up/down or left/right to look in the axis you'd like.